# testing for equality using itemgetter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import takewhile

xs = [ ('foo',1), ('bar',1), ('baz',2) ]
```

`xs` is sorted on the second item - there are no more `1`s after `'bar'`.

```
def item_map(xs):
    getcount = itemgetter(1)
    return list(map(getcount,xs))

print(item_map(xs))
>>> [1, 1, 2]
```

returns a list of the second element of every tuple.

```
def item_take(xs):   
    return list(takewhile(lambda x: x[1] == 1, xs))

print(item_take(xs))
[('foo', 1), ('bar', 1)]
```

returns the tuples that have a second element that == 1.

```
def could_this_work(xs):
    match = itemgetter(1) == 1 
    return list(takewhile(match, xs))

print(could_this_work(xs))
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

does not return the tuples that have a second element that == 1

Is there a way to use `itemgetter` in place of the lambda? Or can `itemgetter` not be used in this way?

EDIT. `takewhile` is being used for a reason. I understand what it does. This function is going to be used on a sorted list. I appreciate that the tuples are backwards for this, but the code that I have used it correct for what I want and expect.

Comment: As @NedBatchelder said in his comment, even the second function you wrote does not do what you expect it to do. Try it with `xs = [ ('foo',1), ('bar',2), ('baz',1) ]`. It should only return `[('foo',1)]`, which is not what you want (according to what you wrote in the original post).

Comment: @jadkik94, I should have been explicit. I have edited to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda function is actually the composition of two functions: `operator.itemgetter(1)` and `operator.eq`.  Doing this in a purely functional style would require a `compose()` function, like this one:

```py
def compose(f, g):
    def composed(x):
        return f(g(x))
    return composed
```

Using this function, you could do

```py
from operator import itemgetter, eq
from functools import partial

def take_items(a):
    return takewhile(compose(partial(eq, 1), itemgetter(1)), a)
```

I don't think this is a godd idea, though.  I would probably go with the straight-forward

```py
def take_items(a):
    for x in a:
        if x[1] != 1:
            break
        yield x
```

I think this requires less thinking on part of the reader of the code.

Comment: I'm know that the for loop is the clearest, but as I am the only one reading the code I try write in a style that challenges me to constantly learn.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
getcount = itemgetter(1)
match = lambda x: getcount(x) == 1
```

What you did commpared the `itemgetter(1)` to 1. This comaprison returns False. Then you call that. `False(x)` won't work, so you have this error.

`itemgetter(n)` is basically a function similar to:

```
def itemgetter(n):
    return lambda x: x[n]
```

You notice that returns another function, comparing it to an `int` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

`itemgetter` doesn't do comparisons, it simply gives you a function that retrieves items.  You'll need to make your own function if you want comparisons.

Also, note that you can use list comprehensions:

```
def could_this_work(xs):
    return [x for x in xs if x[1] == 1]
```

or even generator expressions, which can work lazily on even infinite streams:

```
def could_this_work(xs):
    return (x for x in xs if x[1] == 1)
```

(These do what your English said: get the items with 1 in the second element.  If you want to stop when you find a non-1 element, use Sven's answer.)

Comment: The original code uses `takewhile()`, so it break after the first non-matching item.  This is not the same as the list comprehension you gave.

Comment: You are right, so maybe the list comprehension *is* what the OP is looking for after all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this in real code. Just use the lambda, honestly.

```
from operator import itemgetter, eq
from functools import partial
from itertools import takewhile

def compose_unary(func1, func2):
    return lambda x: func1(func2(x))

def item_take(xs):
    return list(takewhile(compose_unary(partial(eq, 1), itemgetter(1)), xs))
```

Note that `takewhile` doesn't actually do quite what you seem to think; it will stop at the first element that doesn't match the predicate, and ignore anything beyond that point that does.